# edit example queries in fuseki

Tags: sparql, jena, fuseki

Is there a way to change the default example queries in jena fuseki?

I'd like to include a set of sample queries for people to run during a demonstration without popping into another window to copy over the queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows: [`%FUSEKI_HOME%\webapp\js\app\qonsole-config.js`](https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/jena-3.13.1/jena-fuseki2/jena-fuseki-webapp/src/main/webapp/js/app/qonsole-config.js):

```js
/** Standalone configuration for qonsole on index page */

define( [], function() {
  return {
    prefixes: {
      "rdf":      "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
      "rdfs":     "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#",
      "owl":      "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#",
      "xsd":      "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    },
    queries: [
      { "name": "Selection of triples",
        "query": "SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object\nWHERE {\n" +
                 "  ?subject ?predicate ?object\n}\n" +
                 "LIMIT 25"
      },
      { "name": "Selection of classes",
        "query": "SELECT DISTINCT ?class ?label ?description\nWHERE {\n" +
                 "  ?class a owl:Class.\n" +
                 "  OPTIONAL { ?class rdfs:label ?label}\n" +
                 "  OPTIONAL { ?class rdfs:comment ?description}\n}\n" +
                 "LIMIT 25",
        "prefixes": ["owl", "rdfs"]
      }
    ]
  };
} );
```

Comment: I made some changes to the file, but the example queries didn't change, even though they were completely rewritten. Instead, the one of the new queries was set to the default query on start. Is there another step I might be overlooking? (I'm not familiar with Java, so it's likely I'm missing something painfully obvious)

Comment: the problem might have been with Chrome. Tried again in Opera and everything updated.

Comment: Delete cookies and clear local storage for localhost:3030.